# Complex query optimization improve speed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that i would like to optimize:

```
SELECT 
    *, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
FROM (
        SELECT
                SUM(a.id = 1) as KILLS,
                SUM(a.id = 2) as DEATHS,
                SUM(a.id = 3) as WINS,
                tb1.totalPlaytime,
                p.playerName

        FROM
        (
                SELECT
                        player_id,
                        SUM(pg.timeEnded - pg.timeStarted) as totalPlaytime
                FROM playergame pg
                INNER JOIN player p
                        ON pg.player_id = p.id
                WHERE pg.game_id IN(1, 2, 3) 
                GROUP BY
                        p.id
                ORDER BY
                        p.playerName ASC
        ) tb1
        INNER JOIN playeraction pa
                ON pa.player_id = tb1.player_id
        INNER JOIN action a
                ON pa.action_id = a.id
        INNER JOIN player p
                ON pa.player_id = p.id      
        GROUP BY
                p.id
        ORDER BY
            KILLS DESC) tb2
 WHERE tb2.playerName LIKE "%"
```

Somehow i am having the feeling that this is not suited for mysql. I keep a lot of actions in different tables for a good statistical approach but this slows down everything. (perhaps big data?)

This is my *model*

[image: Model]

Now i tried doing the following:

**Combining joins in a view**

I Combined the many JOINS into a VIEW. This gave me no improvements.

**Index the tables**

I indexed the frequently used keys, this did speed up but i can't manage to get the entire resultset below 0.613s.

**Start from the action table and use left joins**

This gave me a somewhat different approach but yet the joins keep being slow (the first example is still the fastest)

indexes:

[image: indexes]

Any hints, tips, additions, improvements are welcome

Comment: well, just how many records are you dealing with? 0.613 seconds to go through a 10 kajillion record database is pretty impressive. 0.613 seconds to scan one single record is pretty pathetic.

Comment: Post the `EXPLAIN` output so we can see where it may be failing to use indexes.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that, i'm going through about 146000 records which should increase rapidly

Comment: Updated original post with the output of the `EXPLAIN` function

Comment: Remove `ORDER BY p.playerName ASC` from the subquery, it is redundant, you don't need to sort records in the subquery, because they are later joined and ordered again in the outer query. In theory the database should optimize queries like this and skip nedeless sort, but I am not sure if MySql is smart enough to do this kind of optimalization. One more question: can 'playergame` table contain a `player_id` value that does not exists in `player.id` ?

Comment: `player_id` cannot contain a value that doesnt exist in `player.id`  and i removed the order by but that increased the time with about 0.004 seconds

Comment: Are there any other action_id than 1,2,3?

Are there any other game_id than 1,2,3?

Can you move the  WHERE clause to the inner query?

Comment: Yes, there can be a lot more action_ids and game_ids i just took the 1,2,3 as example data

Comment: You may try limiting the action table in the join if you know which actions you need:

`INNER JOIN action a ON (pa.action_id = a.id AND a.id IN (1,2,3) AND a.gameid IN (1,2,3))`

Also there is a question if your index on actions is on touple `(gameid, id)` or you have separate indexes on each field?

Comment: The INNER JOIN on the actions (1,2,3) doesnt speed up the process. My indexes are seperate on each field, should i change some to touples?

Comment: Try creating an index `(gameid, id)` in actions. But do not remove the one on actions. And leave added `a.gameid IN (1,2,3)`. If you have many different gameids then it may speed up the query. That is also the case of other tables and joins. So, for `playeraction` add `gameid IN ()` to `JOIN` and create an index on the tuple `(gameid, player_id)`.

Comment: This did speed up the query to 0.362s, added an index on playeraction on the fields (player_id, action_id). the index on (game_id, id) in action didnt speed up much

Comment: There are few more questions one needs to answer like **(1)** which mysql engine do you use? **(2)** are your indexes clustered or not? **(3)** are you really going to use wildcard in the `WHERE` clause? **(4)** maybe it is worth to redesign the structure and have a table with summary with triggers on selects on a a view that would only update the summary with the latest data?  **(5)** remember not to keep indexes you do not use as they will slow down inserts dirastically **(6)** in the most inner query remove `INNER JOIN player p` and change group by to `player_id`

Comment: Im using innoDb, the wildcard is most of the times equal to % and doesnt contain other characters (im using it for searching). I changed the group by (indeed unnecessary join). It might be a good solution to redesign the structure since this is getting quite complex i think.  Thank you for all your help it really helped me!

Comment: No problem. If you think you would like to know more about indexes see [use-the-index-luke.com](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my previous answer as it was wrong and did not help, and here I am just summarizing our conversation in the comments with additional comments from myself

There are several ways to speed up the query.

1. Make sure you are not making any redundant queries.
2. Do as few joins as possible.
3. Make indexes on multiple columns if possible.
4. Make indexes clustered if needed/possible http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html

Regarding the query you wrote in the question:

1. Remove `ORDER BY` in the inner query
2. Remove `INNER JOIN` in the inner query and replace `GROUP BY p.id` by `GROUP BY player_id`
3. Few words on where indexes make sense and where not.

   In your case it would not make sense to have index on `gameid` on table `playergame` because that   probably would return loads of rows. So that is all what you can do about the most inner query.

   The joins can also be a bit optimized if you know what you expect from the tables, i.e., the amount of data they may face. you may think of it as a question are you building database behind a MMO game of FPS. MMO will have millions of users per game, FPS will have only a few. Also different types of games may have different actions. That would imply that you may try to optimize the query by making the index more precise. If you are able to define in the inner join of `action` that `gameid IN (...)` then creating an index on tuple `(gameid, id)` might help.

   Wildcart in `WHERE` clause. You may try to create an index on `playername` but it will only work if you look with a wildcard at the end of your search string, for one in the beginning you would need a separate index, and hope that query optimizer will be smart enough to switch between them each time you make a query.

   Keep in mind that more indexes imply slowed insert and delete, so keep only as few as possible.
4. Another thing would be redesigning the structure a bit. You may still keep the database normalized, but maybe it would be usefull to have a table with summary of some games. You may have a table with summary of games that happened before yesterday, and your query would only summarize the data for today, and then join both tables if needed. Then you could optimize it by either creating and index on timestamp or partitioning table by day. Everything depends on the load you expect.

The topic is rather deep, so everything depends on what is the story behind the data.